# Grouping customers as "others" if sum of sales is below a value

Tags: tableau-api

I want to build a logic in tableau for grouping customers. Basically I want to see a bar graph comparison of customers sales with below logic:

1. Customers whose respective sum of sales is less than 100,000 are grouped as "Others" and shown as one bar
2. Customers whose respective sum of sales is more than 100,000 are shown as individual bars

Please let me know if there is a solution already discussed for this query or for any further details needed to support my question, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if {fixed [Customer Name] : sum([Sales])} > 100000 then
   [Customer Name]
else
   "Other"
end
```

Comment: Alex, appreciate your help! Your solutions perfectly fits my requirement, thanks a lot

Comment: I would like to add that if you create a parameter and use that instead of 100000, then your dashboard users will be able to set the threshold to whatever they want. Using a parameter will make your dashboard a bit more interactive and you will have less maintenance to do when someone wants the threshold changed.